# Overrideable property that can be accessed both by instance and by class

Tags: c#, static

I have an inheritance tree with a bunch of different classes. Each of these classes has some static properties that I need acces to from time to time. Sometimes I need the property of a particular class, and sometimes I need the property of the specific class some polymorphic instance turns out to be.

This would be easy in, say, Java (I think). Just make a bunch of static fields (can these be overriden? I'm not sure). But in C#, non-static fields can ONLY be accessed via an instance (naturally), and static fields can ONLY be accessed via their corresponding class (unnaturally).

And, you can't "overload" by, er, *staticity*. If a class has a static and a non static `Foo`, doing `instance.Foo` fails because it is unclear to the compiler which `Foo` you're referring to even though it's impossible you're referring to the static one since it's disallowed.

Ok, I'll provide some code. Say I have this:

```
class Base
{
    public static readonly string Property = "Base";
}

class Child1 : Base
{
    public static readonly new string Property = "Child 1";
}

class Child2 : Base
{
    public static readonly new string Property = "Child 2";
}
```

And then, somewhere:

```
public void SomeMethod(Base instance)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(instance.Property);  // This doesn't work.
}
```

And somewhere else:

```
public void SomeOtherMethod()
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(Child2.Property);
}
```

I want something like that, that actually works.

Comment: This question is unclear. Maybe you should post some code showing what you want to do. Pattern it after how you'd do it in Java if you like. Java has different ideas of what "static" means, including a kind of static that's not really static at all (related to nested classes).

Comment: @Peter Ok, done. Not in Java though as I'm not a Java programmer.

Answer (score 1):

As [Peter Duniho said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26434797/overrideable-property-that-can-be-accessed-both-by-instance-and-by-class/26435009#comment41514778_26435009), this can be done with **reflection**.

For example, these can be defined within the **base class**:

```
public const string Property = "Base";

public virtual string InstanceProperty
{
    get
    {
        return (string)this.GetType()
            .GetField("Property", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
            .GetValue(null); 
    }
}
```

And then each **derived class** just has to redefine `Property` using the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you'll do in C# is something like this:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual string InstanceProperty
    {
        get { return StaticProperty; }
    }

    public static string StaticProperty
    {
        get { return "BaseClass"; }
    }
}

public class Derived1Base : BaseClass
{
    public override string InstanceProperty
    {
        get { return StaticProperty; }
    }

    public new static string StaticProperty
    {
        get { return "Derived1Base"; }
    }
}

public class Derived1Derived1Base : Derived1Base
{
}

public class Derived2Base : BaseClass
{
    public override string InstanceProperty
    {
        get { return StaticProperty; }
    }

    public new static string StaticProperty
    {
        get { return "Derived2Base"; }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is also possible to use reflection, though IMHO that would be an inferior solution. As far as this particular solution (John's example) goes, it's IMHO the right way to do it. However, I would make the static members string consts instead of properties (more in line with the original example, but using "const" instead of "static readonly"). E.g. "public const string Property = "Base"", then "new public const string Property = "Child 1"", etc. That code would be much more concise and more efficient.

Comment: @Peter Constants are fine except I need an array of string too which I don't think can be constant.

Comment: @GerardoMarset: that's correct. Things which cannot be expressed as compile-time literals cannot be const (+). But you might as well make things const when they can be. (+) (I don't recall the exact language spec requirement off the top of my head, but this a reasonable generalization).